# Why is my PHP cURL request to this API not pulling any data when the same request works in Postman?

Tags: php, api, curl

EDIT: I have added a conditional statement to my code to check the result of curl_error($ch). It is apparently not returning an error. I have also added a curl_setop to set CURLOPT_POST to true.

I am trying to connect to an API using PHP and cURL and pull back a JSON response to be displayed on the page however while my initial request for an Access Token is successful with a simple GET request, I am not being returned any data by my subsequent POST requests.

I have been able to use Postman (screenshot below) to test the POST request and successfully receive a response, so the data I am sending in the POST request appears to be correct and the Access Token appears to work however when my PHP makes the request it appears that nothing is returned when I use **json_decode** and then **print_r** to display the contents of the JSON response.

I am very unfamiliar with cURL and so my code has been taken from a tutorial at this link: https://www.codexworld.com/post-receive-json-data-using-php-curl/. The API documentation is provided at this link: [NUACOM API - Reports](https://api.nuacom.ie/#tag/Reports)

The following is my code:

```php
$nuacom_get_api_key_url = "https://api.nuacom.ie/login_digest?email=abc@xyz.com&pass=123"; //dummy credentials for stackoverflow
$response_json = file_get_contents($nuacom_get_api_key_url);
$response_array = json_decode($response_json,true);
    
$session_token = $response_array['session_token'];

// API URL
$url = 'https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats';

// Create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);

// Setup request to send json via POST
$data = array(
    "group_by" => "day",
    "time_from" => "2020-08-27 00:00:01",
    "time_to" => "2020-08-27 23:59:59",
    "queue" => "1",
    "client-security-token" => $session_token
);
            
$payload = json_encode($data);

// Set the request type to POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// Attach encoded JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

// Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

// Return response instead of outputting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Execute the POST request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors'; //this is the line that is executed
}

// Close cURL resource
curl_close($ch);
            
$response_array = json_decode($result);

print_r($response_array);
```

Postman successful response:

[image: postman]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure it's something small that I am missing due to lack of familiarity with cURL and POST requests.

Comment: could you run curl_error($ch) before the curl_close and show the output? Also I am unsure whether or not you really need $payload = json_encode(array($data)); or if json_encode($data) would not suffice. You might also be missing the curl_setopt that makes it a POST request

Comment: @j4g0 I have edited the post to add that to my code and the result. It is apparently not returning any errors.

Comment: did you try to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); before curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); to make sure it is a POST request?

Comment: @j4g0 I have tried that also and there is no change. I have updated the post with the added code.

Comment: and you were sure you needed to wrap the $data array in another array?

Comment: You would send an array to the endpoint and if I understand their documentation they do not expect an array

Comment: @j4g0 apologies, I am still very unfamiliar in this area - if not using an array how would I handle it? If you can point me in the direction of a tutorial or documentation I can take it from there

Comment: If your postman works properly, it could also "export" the php/curl code to make your like easier (click on `code` and select `php`). why you don't use this feature?

Comment: @AliKhalili that has worked perfectly, thank you - I was not aware Postman provided that functionality - could you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in postman you're sending the data via the URL, and in curl you're sending the data in the request body json-encoded, the equivalent curl code to the postman would be:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats?' . http_build_query(array(
        "group_by" => "day",
        "time_from" => "2020-08-27 00:00:01",
        "time_to" => "2020-08-27 23:59:59",
        "queue" => "1",
        "client-security-token" => $session_token
    )),
    CURLOPT_POST => 1
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

... but reading the documentation at https://api.nuacom.ie/#operation/QueueReports , seems they want

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'client-security-token: '.$session_token,
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(array(
        "group_by" => "day",
        "time_from" => "2020-08-27 00:00:01",
        "time_to" => "2020-08-27 23:59:59",
        "queue" => "1",
    )),
    CURLOPT_POST => 1
));
curl_exec($ch);
```

hence it seems putting everything  in the URL, as you're doing with Postman, is undefined/undocumented behavior, and it just happened to work anyway..

also the `client-security-token` does NOT go in the json, per the authentication documentation, it can go in the header, or in the url, but NOT in the json, your curl code is trying to put it in the JSON (while your Postman code put it in the url, together with everything else..)

Answer (score 3):

My bad. Maybe it's easier as an answer instead of comments so I can format the important parts.

You are creating an array with the data you want to send:

```
$data = array(
    "group_by" => "day",
    "time_from" => "2020-08-27 00:00:01",
    "time_to" => "2020-08-27 23:59:59",
    "queue" => "1",
    "client-security-token" => $session_token
);
```

and when you json_encode it to send it to the API you currently wrap it in another array

```
$payload = json_encode(array($data));
```

the result would be:

```
[{"group_by":"day","time_from":"2020-08-27 00:00:01","time_to":"2020-08-27 23:59:59","queue":"1","client-security-token":"token"}]
```

a json array. The api documentation for the "queue_inbound_stats" endpoint seems to ask for the data not being wrapped in another array like so

```
{"group_by":"day","time_from":"2020-08-27 00:00:01","time_to":"2020-08-27 23:59:59","queue":"1","client-security-token":"token"}
```

so just omit wrapping your $data array again:

```
$payload = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: I have made this change and unfortunately it has made no difference. I have updated the original post with the current code.

Comment: what is the output of print_r($response_array); ?

Comment: it appears to be an empty string as the only output that appears on the page is that of "'Operation completed without any errors'"

Comment: your screenshot suggests that you are using query parameters when using postman instead of sending a request body. Did you try to add your Data as parameters i.E. https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats?group_by="day"&queue="1"&... and not send the POSTFIELDS with the curl request?

Comment: I have tried that yes - here is the code sample - this returns a PHP error of "Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats?client-security-token='token'&group='day'&queue='1'&time_from='2020-08-27 00:00:01'&time_to='2020-08-27 23:59:59'): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"

Comment: $nuacom_get_api_key_url = "https://api.nuacom.ie/v1/reports/queue_inbound_stats?client-security-token=" . $session_token . "&group='day'&queue='1'&time_from='2020-08-27 00:00:01'&time_to='2020-08-27 23:59:59'";
   $response_json = file_get_contents($nuacom_get_api_key_url);
   $response_array = json_decode($response_json,true);
   print_r($response_array);

Comment: the error indicates, that there is no file at the specified url "https://api.nuacom.ie/login_digest?email=abc@xyz.com&pass=123" . The documentation suggests you have to make a get request to that endpoint instead. Though the documentation also states that you have to make a post request with a request body to "queue_inbound_stats" so maybe you can ask their support to clarify since your postman request suggests otherwise

Comment: I consulted their support and they were able to connect to the API and use the queue_inbound_stats on their side so it was apparent it was an issue with my PHP code which they are not bound to support.

Answer (score 1):

If your postman request works fine, you can easily export your request to php/curl. This nice feature make your life easier. Just click on `code` button and you can export your request to curl, php/curl, C#, Go, and several other options.

[image]